# Bitbucket rest api direction parameter

Tags: bash, rest, bitbucket

I try to get all pull-requests from the branch using

`curl ... /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests?direction=OUTGOING&at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmybranch`
but I get all opened pull requests.

How can I get only requests that really outgoing from the branch?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
curl --location -u username:password --request GET ' http://bitbucketurl/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repoSlug}/pull-requests?at=refs/heads/branch&direction=outgoing&state=ALL'
```